# MAMP install Redis extension on Mac

Tags: php, macos, mamp

How do I install an extension on MAMP (not PRO)?

I have edited my `.zshrc` file to add:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/opt/local/bin
```

When I run `php --ini` I get this:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
>   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf
>
> Loaded Configuration File: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini
>
> Scan for additional
>   .ini files in: (none)
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

However when I do any changes in that `php.ini` file, I see no changes as if some "global" changes overwrite it. I tried invalidating the ini by adding gibberish to it, but I got no error. After each change I do a MAMP stop/start, and PHP cache is set to 'off'.

Since I had `redis.so` from before, I have manually moved it to extension folder, but `pecl install redis` fails with this message:

```
downloading redis-4.2.0.tgz ...
Starting to download redis-4.2.0.tgz (235,569 bytes)
.................................................done: 235,569 bytes
25 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

But `phpize -v` returns

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
```

I have `autoconf` installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. The main problem was in PECL/PEAR paths. Once I did this:

```
pear config-set php_ini /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini
pecl config-set php_ini /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini
```

The issue was resolved